# Is it possible to make an empty window using only the standard library?

Tags: rust, window, std

I want to make a game using only the standard library to better understand Rust.  How would I do this only using Rust's standard library (preferably without using any `unsafe` blocks)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library doesn't provide any GUI primitives. So if you don't want to rely on external libraries, you will have to use FFI to your platform's GUI APIs. And it will definitely involve unsafe. But I recommend you to just use an existing library - GUIs are hard.

Comment: I second the "GUIs are hard", in fact, even TUIs are hard! If handling user-input feels easy, wait until the user wants to select something to copy or cut it. Suddenly you need to match the position of the cursor/pointer to whatever element it's on down to the index of the specific character... it's all downhill from there.